# C# casting double to float error

Tags: c#, casting

In my code I have the following where _realScore is a float.

```
_realScore=Math.Ceiling(_realScore);
```

But I get the following error
Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

So I assume this means I must cast the result of Math.Ceiling to type float. But nothing I try works. Can anyone help?

Comment: Search for error messages first. This is a trivial case of a cast operation. Or, perhaps `_realScore` could be made a double. (Ther is little reason to choose float over double as a primary datatype except in cases of "insane amount of values and/or math".)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584793/math-pow-gives-cannot-implicitly-convert-type-double-to-float-error , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868575/how-to-get-output-of-a-variable-as-float-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
_realScore = (float) Math.Ceiling(_realScore);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use:

```
_realScore = (float) Math.Ceiling(_realScore);
```

`Math.Ceiling` has only 2 overloads, one accepting Decimal, one Double. When you use a float as parameter, the overload with the Double parameter is used. It returns Double as well which cannot be implicitely cast to float - you need to cast explicitely.